# How to hide all widgets in a QGridLayout() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently looking for a smart way to start a game made in PyCharm by using the PyQt library and I wanted to try and hide several widgets, or complete Layouts but the function .hide() doesn't work on complete layouts.

Is there a code to hide layouts completely or is hiding all the widget in that box the way to go?

If the answer is the latter, how can I make it easier for me than to go through every single widget and add the .hide() extension to them. Can I collect all those widgets in some sort of parent and then just parent.hide() as well as parent.show() ?

The code looks like this atm:

```
    playerbox = QGridLayout()
    playerbox.addWidget(self.player1, 0, 0)
    playerbox.addWidget(self.player2, 0, 1)
    playerbox.addWidget(self.stake, 1, 0)
    playerbox.addWidget(self.money, 1, 1)
    playerbox.addWidget(betButton, 2, 0)
    playerbox.addWidget(foldButton, 2, 1)
    playerbox.addWidget(bettingtext,3,0)
```

And the playerbox is supposed to be a box in a game that displays several items. I just want this box not to show anything before the game has started (this is done when the user press start but this has already been dealt with).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I like this one:

```
[playerbox.itemAt(i).widget().hide() for i in 
    range(playerbox.rowCount()*playerbox.columnCount()) if 
    playerbox.itemAt(i)]
```

the `if` clause is required since you could have empty spots in your grid, and then `itemAt()` returns `None`.

Comment: Or of course you could have saved your widgets in a (python) list.